# Drop rows based on threshold condition on columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to first get the column names that have Null percentage values greater than 10% in  a dataframe`df`.
To get that, I am writing the below condition but it is not working.
and then l have to drop the rows that have null values for those columns.

```
df.dropna(how=all , subset = [((df.isnull().sum()/len(df.index))*100) > 10])
```

or 
can we use thresh argument here instead of subset and specifying the condition in Thresh argument?
please suggest.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. _I want to first get the column names that have Null percentage values greater than 10% in a dataframe df. To get that, i am writing the below condition but it is not working. and then i have to drop the rows that that have null values for those columns._ Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: After first sentence your question is not understandable, kindly give proper explanation.